# I want to know main things to learn before starting module development in Prestashop?

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.5

I want to know main things to learn before starting module development in Prestashop ?
Some use full website url's and videos , tutorials which will cover up important points and also clear my concepts .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a broad question, but let me give you some advice.

1) Google for How to develop Prestashop Modules.

2) Search for youtube videos on youtube

3) Search for some books for Prestahsop

4) Read Prestashop documentation http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS15/English+documentation

Answer (score 1):

The place to start from is http://doc.prestashop.com/dashboard.action

Recently I found a good tutorial at http://www.technoreply.com/how-to-create-a-prestashop-1-5-module/
I hope it helps